How can I get the width and height of page two of multi-page image using the System.Drawing.Image class?
Using the System.Drawing.Image library in .Net 4.8, how can I get the width and height of page 2 of an image?
Currently I use the following to get the first page's width and height.  But not sure on how to get the second pages width and height.  At first I just thought all pages in the images would be the same size, but it seems my test image (of three images) has very different sizes.
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  using (Image tif = Image.FromStream(stream, false, false))
  {
    float width = tif.PhysicalDimension.Width;
    float height = tif.PhysicalDimension.Height;

    _imageSize = new Size((int)width, (int)height);
  }
}

Also tried using this method but feel like I'm doing something wrong because of the time it takes saving the bitmap to a bytestream.  It's really slow.
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
  using (Bitmap bm = (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(fs, false, false))
  {
    int frameCount = bm.GetFrameCount(FrameDimension.Page);

    if (pageNum < 1)
      throw new Exception("The page number can't be less then 1.");

    if (pageNum > frameCount)
      throw new Exception($"The page number ({pageNum}) can not exceed the total pages ({frameCount}).");

    bm.SelectActiveFrame(FrameDimension.Page, pageNum - 1);

    MemoryStream byteStream = new MemoryStream();
    
    // This is REALLY slow, tried using bmp format too
    bm.Save(byteStream, ImageFormat.Tiff);

    Image page = Image.FromStream(byteStream);
    float width = page.PhysicalDimension.Width;
    float height = page.PhysicalDimension.Height;

    return new Size((int)width, (int)height);
  }
}


Check the class here: How to determine if an Image is Grayscale, more specifically the FrameSourceAddRange() method. It lists all the Frames in an image source and returns information about each Frame in the source, size included. It uses System.Windows.Media.Imaging, though. The information is extracted leveraging the dedicated decoder's capabilities, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.TiffBitmapDecoder, in this case
